# How to Create WF with C#

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, development, workflow

I have learned about Workflow by dropping and clicking and the next phase is learn how to create WF with C# based this link
(http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Reimagine-SharePoint-Development/Translating-Custom-Code-Workflows-to-SharePoint-2013)

What material, link etc can you recommend me to learn about creating WF with C# coding? I have previous knowledge in ASP.net, regular c# coding etc but not in relation to WF with C# code.

Comment: i am also desperately looking for creating custom state machine workflows with visual studio 2013 on sharepoint 2013 . thats associated to a splist or spdocument library.if its asscoiated with a custom content type that has aspx as association form.

Answer (score 1):

There are basically two types of workflows we can create in Visual Studio:

1. Sequential Workflow.
2. State Machine Workflow.

Following articles gives you basic idea behind both WF:

Article-1 : [Difference Between Sequential Workflow & State machine workflow?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/85879/difference-between-sequential-workflow-state-machine-workflow) 
Article-2 :[MSDN Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vssharepointtoolsblog/archive/2008/07/24/what-is-the-difference-between-sequential-and-state-machine-workflows.aspx)

Following articles helps you to create sequential workflows in visual studio:

1. https://sergeluca.wordpress.com/2011/01/06/step-by-step-tutorial-creating-workflows-for-sharepoint-2010-step-115/
2. https://babu143.wordpress.com/2012/12/24/creating-a-sequential-workflow-for-sharepoint-2010-using-visual-studio-a-step-by-step-guide/
3. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh824675%28v=office.14%29.aspx
4. http://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/2012/12/20/sequential-workflow-in-sharepoint-2010-using-visual-studio-2010-aspx-2/
5. http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/how-to-create-sequential-workflow-in-sharepoint-2010-using-visual-studio-2010

Comment: have you worked on this previosuly with  SP 2013 as  platform for creating sequential / state machine, please lets us know and  what steps need to be created for creating the same in SP 2013 platform and how to take actions like approve /reject/send back to requestor state using the pure C#.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/416393/Create-a-Workflow-using-Visual-Studio-2010) is the good example to start with SP workflow using Visual studio.

Please follow the below steps:

1-Start with a Sequential Workflow. Start Visual Studio and create a new project from the     template SharePoint --> Sequential Workflow.

2-In the next screen select the option Site Workflow.

3-In the next screen, leave the default option saying the user manually starts the Workflow.

4-Create Activity

**What is an Activity?**

A Workflow consists of a series of Activities. We can add Activities using the Toolbox. There are different types of Activities like Code Activity, SendEmail, etc.

5-Drag and drop a Code Activity from the toolbox.

6-Add code for the Activity, add code for this Activity. Double click on the codeActivity1

```
    private void codeActivity1_ExecuteCode(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    using (SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Web)
    {
    SPList list = web.Lists["Manager"];
    foreach (SPListItem item in list.Items)
    {
        if (item["Address"] == null)
        {
            item["Address"] = "PLEASE SET THE ADDRESS!";

            item.Update();
        }
      }
     }
    }
```

7-Build and Deploy the Solution.

Comment: You don't need to manually dispose SPWeb from SPContext.Current.Web

Comment: But , this will have problems when creating custom content types with aspx forms. how to create a custom approval form using the aspx pages / site pages? how to achieve these things?  here is MVP Serge's blog about it :https://sergeluca.wordpress.com/2013/04/08/sharepoint-2013-workflows-and-content-types-forget-it/  also another thread discusses about this : http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/184624/associate-sharepoint-2013-workflow-with-a-content-type

Comment: From MSDN: “Unlike previous versions, SharePoint 2013 does not support workflows that are scoped to a content type (SPContentType). However, the messaging infrastructure is extensible, so it can support any arbitrary scope. As a developer, you can set the EventSourceId property on a given WorkflowSubscription instance to any guid. You can then use that EventSourceId value to call PublishEvent(Guid, String, IDictionary<String, Object>), which triggers a new workflow instance of the specified WorkflowSubscription.”. I haven't found a workaround either. Case closed.