# Associate SharePoint 2013 workflow with a content type

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, workflow, reusable-workflow

Continuing from my previous call for help - [SharePoint 2013 Reusable workflow doesn't pick up fields in a different site collection](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/184541/sharepoint-2013-reusable-workflow-doesnt-pick-up-fields-in-a-different-site-col)

I assume you can associate SharePoint 2013 workflows with content types:
[image]

After I move the reusable workflow to another site collection, how can I re-associate it with a content type in that site collection. I am currently using PowerShell to associate it with a list but that doesn't seem to work very well.

```
> $wfm = New-object
> Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServices.WorkflowServicesManager($Web)
> $defSevice = $wfm.GetWorkflowDeploymentService() $wfDefs =
> $defSevice.EnumerateDefinitions($false) $wfDef = $wfDefs | where
> {$_.DisplayName -eq $WorkflowName}
> 
> $wfsubService = $wfm.GetWorkflowSubscriptionService()
> 
> $sub = New-object
> Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServices.WorkflowSubscription
> $sub.DefinitionId = $wfDef.Id $sub.Enabled = $true $sub.Name =
> $wfDef.DisplayName
> 
> $startOptions = New-Object
> "System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection[System.String]"
> $startOptions.Add("WorkflowStart") $sub.EventTypes = $startOptions
> 
> $sub.SetProperty("HistoryListId", $HistoryListId)
> $sub.SetProperty("TaskListId", $TaskListId)
> 
> $wfSubService.PublishSubscriptionForList($sub, $ApprovalListId);
```

Searched the intrawebz, but can't seem to find a solution on how to associate reusable workflows with content types. Can anyone shed any light on this? Proper ways or workarounds are welcome. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, did you get the solution? If yes , can you share how to associate the workflow to the content type

Comment: Apparently there is no way. I ended up associating it with a list: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/184541/sharepoint-2013-reusable-workflow-doesnt-pick-up-fields-in-a-different-site-col/184837#184837

Answer (score 1):

From MSDN: “*Unlike previous versions, SharePoint 2013 does not support workflows that are scoped to a content type (`SPContentType`). However, the messaging infrastructure is extensible, so it can support any arbitrary scope. As a developer, you can set the `EventSourceId` property on a given WorkflowSubscription instance to any guid. You can then use that `EventSourceId` value to call `PublishEvent(Guid, String, IDictionary<String, Object>)`, which triggers a new workflow instance of the specified `WorkflowSubscription`.*”. I haven't found a workaround either. Case closed.

Comment: Why they have removed this feature!! what is the workaround for this!! Why why why we cannot use Content Type to Reuseable WFs