# how to associate a sharepoint 2013 designer worklfow to a content type using csom

Tags: sharepoint-designer, content-type, designer-workflow, dashboard-designer-2013

i want to associate a SharePoint 2013 designer workflow to a content type using CSOM. Has anybody implemented it?

Answer (score 1):

I've been researching for the same answer for 2 days. Apparently there is no way on how to assign a SharePoint 2013 workflow to a Content Type. MSDN says:

*“Unlike previous versions, SharePoint 2013 does not support workflows that are scoped to a content type (SPContentType). However, the messaging infrastructure is extensible, so it can support any arbitrary scope. As a developer, you can set the EventSourceId property on a given WorkflowSubscription instance to any guid. You can then use that EventSourceId value to call PublishEvent(Guid, String, IDictionary), which triggers a new workflow instance of the specified WorkflowSubscription.”*

If you specify a Content Type when creating a new workflow in SharePoint Designer it will only allow to use fields available in the Content Type, but it won't be associated to the content type.

The only workarounds are to create SharePoint 2010 workflows (which can be associated with content types) and start them from within SharePoint 2013 workflows **or** publish workflow subscriptions to lists:

[Associate SharePoint 2013 workflow with a content type](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/184624/associate-sharepoint-2013-workflow-with-a-content-type?noredirect=1#comment194963_184624)

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sharepointdesigner/2012/08/17/how-to-trigger-a-sharepoint-2010-workflow-from-a-sharepoint-2013-workflow/